# How can I remove duplicate condition checking in Java?

Tags: java, duplicates

```
var Task= Condition1
            ? (CommonCondition ? doThis1 : doThis2)
            : Condition2? (CommonCondition ? doThis3  : doThis4 )
                    : (CommonCondition ? doThis5   : doThis6);
```

How do I avoid repeatedly checking `CommonCondition` value in the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

1. The order of checking the conditions may be changed so that `CommonCondition` is checked once but the other conditions will have to be checked twice in each branch:

```java
var Task= CommonCondition 
    ? (Condition1 ? doThis1 : Condition2 : doThis3 : doThis5) 
    : (Condition1 ? doThis2 : Condition2 : doThis4 : doThis6);
```

2. Implement a 2D array of `Task` or possibly `Supplier<Task>` and use `CommonCondition` to define row index, and the other conditions to define column index:

```
Task[][] arr = {
    {doThis1, doThis3, doThis5},
    {doThis2, doThis4, doThis6}
};
int row = CommonCondition ? 0 : 1;
int col = Condition1 ? 0 : Condition2 ? 1 : 2;
var Task = arr[row][col];
```

3. Similarly, a plain array of `Task`s may be used, then the conditions should be used to calculate indexes:

```java
Task[] arr = { doThis1, doThis2, doThis3, doThis4, doThis5, doThis6 };

int i = Condition1 ? 0 : Condition2 ? 1 : 2;
int j = CommonCondition ? 0 : 1;

var Task = arr[2 * i + j];
```